# How to get series Description from Findscu in dcmtk

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

Now i am working with the DCMTK 3.6 for communicating between Pacs and client side. Here I am using **FINDSCU** for getting list from pacs server. I am using following bat file code to get the list of series .

```
findscu.exe -aet  ACME1 -aec  ACME_WRITE --study -k 0008,0052=SERIES -k 0020,000D=1.2.840.113619.2.312.4120.11688878.10861.1424141038.480 -k 0020,0010=1854 -k 0008,0060 -k 0020,000E -k 0020,0011 -k 0008,103E -v  192.168.3.19  104 >C:\Users\KARTIK\AppData\Local\Temp\\matlab_dcmstudies_tmpfile.txt
```

By using above code i can get series number, series UID and Modality .
Now my question is

**1. how to get series description by using the above code?**

I am also tried with send tag code of series description **(0008 , 103e)** with above code but there is no value is returning from server side.

Comment: Probably the SeriesDescription is not supported from Pacs on Q/R level, did you checked the Dicom Conformance Statement from the Pacs system?

Comment: Is there any other way is there to get series description ?

Comment: If the (optional) Series Description is not supported by the Q/R SCP, you can only retrieve the object (possibly without pixel data, but that's another story) and determine the Series Description from the DICOM dataset,

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: 
Looking into Dicom Conformance Statement is a good advice.

If PACS is following the standard, it's just an optional attribute. Some PACS just don't support it.

see also http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part04.html#sect_C.6.1.1 (C.6.1.1.4 Series Level)

Comment: Series Description (0008,103E) is definitely a series-level attribute. Not sure where you read that it should be on image level.

Comment: @J.Riesmeier, please read section C.6.1.1.4 Series Level, there is no SeriesDescription.

Comment: According to DICOM PS 3.4 Table C.6-3 (http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part04/sect_C.6.html#table_C.6-3), "All Other Attributes at Series Level" are optional. This also includes the Series Description.

Comment: @J.Riesmeier, I'm open for discussion. But "All Other Attributes at Series Level" doesn't indicate it's a series level attribute. According to existence "All other Attributes at Patient/Study/Instance/Composite Object Instance Level"  just being optionally queryable in that level is not equal to be attribute of that level. I could then say, it's a patient level attribute. Ok, maybe I then should also not say it's an image level attribute (I would fixup my answer accoringly). Please compare to the StudyDescription which is listed in StudyLevel or PatientComments which is listet in PatientLevel.

Comment: OK, here's the long version. According to PS3.4 Section C.3.1 "The series level is below the study level and contains Attributes associated with the Series, Frame of Reference and Equipment IEs of the Composite IODs as defined in PS3.3." According to PS3.3, the Series IE contains - amongst others - the General Series Module, which contains the Series Description. So, Series Description is a series-level attribute - q.e.d. :)

Comment: Ok I'm convinced. Thx for the long explanation